# Javascript, object with set lifetime?

Tags: javascript, arrays, settimeout, setinterval, lifetime

I have run in to a problem I do not know how to code in JavaScript really. The thing is I would like to be able to create a lot of objects added to an Array. when objects are created to be added to this array they will have a "lifetime". When this lifetime runs out this object should be removed from the array.

What Im trying to build here is a particle system where particles will vanish from being rendered after the particles lifetime in question have expired.

Anyone who have a good idea or example for this?

I have thought about using `setTimeout`, `setInterval` and `clearInterval` but not sure how this would be most effective.

Comment: Could you provide some boundaries, e.g. the maximum number of objects or the minimum lifetime? One idea could be to use a priority queue, periodically test the first `n` elements whether they expired and remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DkhQ7/4/)?

Update for Felix Kling:

```
var a = [], next = function() {
    a = a.slice(0,-1);
    document.body.innerHTML += a.length + "<br />";
    if (a.length != 0)
        setTimeout(next, 100);
};
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    a.push({hi: 1});
}
setTimeout(next, 100);​
```

Comment: Depending on the number of elements, creating a `setTimeout` for every single element is not a good idea. It will have a performance impact on the browser.

Comment: Performance is something which should always be considered ;) I provided an other idea in my comment to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code sample of **micha**. On every call of "next" function you can update the state of you particles (position, velocity, etc). Also you can track the time of the creation of the particles and on every "next" call check if the current time minus the creation time exceeds certain constant and if it does then remove the particles. Depending on the required quality of the animation you may want to reduce the time between timeouts, e.g. `setTimeout(next, 25);`
Good luck :)